# Trying to Knit but can't because read excel function is not being recognized in R

Tags: r, excel

My whole program is working but when I try to knit to a document the same error is being thrown.

```
Quitting from lines 3-78 (Untitled.spin.Rmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "read_excel"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Execution halted
```

I don't under stand why.  Where are the first 5 lines of my code.

```
Dataset_Stats1Project <- read_excel(Users/jamiestokes16/Desktop/Dataset_WomeninGov5.xlsx)
#Descriptive stats for important variables 
summary(Dataset_WomeninGov$Wcongress) 
summary(Dataset_WomeninGov$Wgov)
summary(Dataset_WomeninGov$Wleg)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Include `library(readxl)`, or if necessary install first `install.packages("readxl"); library(readxl)`.

Answer (score 5):

When you knit a document, knitr essentially creates a new R session for the code to run in. So any packages loaded session will not be accessible unless you load them directly within the .Rmd file.

I always find it easiest to include a chunk at the start of the document loading any packages used:

````
```{r LoadPackages, include = FALSE}    
library(readlx)
# add other packages here
```
````